# Dynamically cast to each array type

Tags: java, casting, refactoring, pmd, static-code-analysis

I am using the following method to print all bundle contents in any possible case. The problem is that PMD is reporting both [`NcssCount`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.13.0/pmd_rules_java_design.html#ncsscount) and [`CyclomaticComplexity`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.13.0/pmd_rules_java_design.html#cyclomaticcomplexity). I would like to improve the code so as to get rid of the warnings and not just supress them.

```
private static String bundleToString(Bundle bundle) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("Bundle[");

    if (bundle == null) {
        out.append("null");
    } else {
        boolean first = true;
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            if (!first) {
                out.append(", ");
            }

            out.append(key).append('=');

            Object value = bundle.get(key);

            if (value instanceof int[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((int[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof byte[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((byte[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof boolean[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((boolean[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof short[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((short[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof long[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((long[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof float[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((float[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof double[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((double[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof String[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((String[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof CharSequence[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((CharSequence[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof Parcelable[]) {
                out.append(Arrays.toString((Parcelable[]) value));
            } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
                out.append(bundleToString((Bundle) value));
            } else {
                out.append(value);
            }

            first = false;
        }
    }

    out.append(']');
    return out.toString();
}
```

I've tried to split the code in two parts with the following logic but the `NcssCount` and `CyclomaticComplexity` just moved to the new method that does all the array casting.

```
if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray()) {
   // the new method to call all the array casts
   newMethodThatSuffersFromTheSameProblem(out, value);
} else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
    out.append(bundleToString((Bundle) value));
} else {
    out.append(value);
}
```

Can I somehow do a dynamic cast to each array type?

```
if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray()) {
   out.append(Arrays.toString((<cast-to-class-array-[]>) value));
}
```

I've also tried `out.append(Arrays.toString(value.getClass().cast(value)));` but gets a compilation error `Cannot resolve method 'toString(capture<? extends java.lang.Object>)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
} else if (value instanceof String[]) {
  out.append(Arrays.toString((String[]) value));
} else if (value instanceof CharSequence[]) {
  out.append(Arrays.toString((CharSequence[]) value));
} else if (value instanceof Parcelable[]) {
  out.append(Arrays.toString((Parcelable[]) value));
```

These 3 `if`s could be replaced with one

```
} else if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray())
  out.append(Arrays.toString((Object[]) value));
```

For the rest you can have static `Map<Class, Function<Object, String>> convertors` and pre-fill it as

```
convertors.put(int[].class, value -> Arrays.toString((int [])value));
...
```

and then use

```
Function<Object, String> convertor = convertors.get(value.getClass());
if (convertor != null) {
  out.append(convertor.apply(value));
} else ...
```

**FOR OLDER ANDROID WHERE LAMBDAS ARE NOT AVAILABLE**

```
interface ToString { String convert(Object object); }
...
static Map<Class, ToString> convertors = new HashMap();
convertors.put(int[].class, new ToString() { public String convert(Object value) { return Arrays.toString((int [])value); }}); 
...
```

and then use

```
ToString convertor = convertors.get(value.getClass());
if (convertor != null) {
  out.append(convertor.convert(value));
} else ...
```

Comment: although the solution looks clear and nice `convert.apply(value)` requires Android API 24 and above :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android. Does it miss lambdas or just `Function` interface? There are workarounds for both but if it doesn't have lambdas then you will have to write more boilerplate code.

Comment: The `Function` interface is the problem it only available from Android 7.0 (Nougat, API 24) and my target at the moment is 4.4 (KitKat). https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function

Comment: so all you need is to define your own Function interface `interface Function<T,R> { R apply(T input); }`

Comment: I updated answer to provide mapping without lambdas and `Function` interface

Comment: I desided to go with the API 24 solution and just add a suppresswarning for the older APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t test it now, but what is wrong with

```
if (value == null) {
   // do whatever you want;
} else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
   out.append(bundleToString((Bundle) value));
} else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
   out.append(Arrays.toString((Object[]) value));
} else {
   out.append(value);
}
```

BTW 1: The NCSS and related parameters are hints. If you have 20 different cases, you have. While you always should think about too big numbers, sometimes @SuppressWarning is the right solution.

BTW 2: What are the reasons to make a static bundleToString(Bundle) instead of overriding Bundle.toString()?

Comment: `Bundle` is a class from Android Framework... even if you are able to extend it and do the override in that case the system will return its own class.